# Herbrand Quotient: Formula for $|K^*/(K^*)^n|$

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

NB: Please restrict answers to hints and not solutions.

Problem: Use the theory of the Herbrand quotient $q(A)=H^{0}(A)/H^{1}(A)$ to show that, if $K$ is a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$, and $U_n$ is the set of nth roots of unity in $K$, then
$|K^*/(K^*)^n|=n|U_n|/|n|_K$.

Here is my working so far. Let $G$ be a cyclic group of order $n$ generated by $\sigma$ and define automorphisms $\Delta=1-\sigma$ and $N=1+\sigma+\sigma^2+...+\sigma^{n-1}$.

Let $G$ act trivially on $K^*$. Then Hilbert's Theorem 90 says that $H^1(K^*)$ is trivial, so $q(K^*)=H^0(K^*)=|Ker(\Delta)| /|Im(N)| =K^*/(K^*)^n$. So it's enough to show that $q(K^*)=n|U_n|/|n|_K$.

Next we notice that there is a short exact sequence
$0 \rightarrow U_n \rightarrow K^* \rightarrow (K^*)^n \rightarrow 0$, where the third arrow is 'take the nth power'. Here, however, I get confused. Doesn't the existence of this sequence imply (via the group isomorphism theorem) that $|K^*/(K^*)^n|=|U_n|$ without the extra factor of $n/|n|_K$ ?

I repeat that I would prefer answers to sort out this confusion with this last point, rather than giving away the answer to the problem.

Comment: First, since all groups are multiplicative the ends of your sequence look better as $1$ rather than $0$. Second, that exact sequence implies $K^*/U_n \cong (K^*)^n$, not that $K^*/(K^*)^n \cong U_n$. What you wrote is already wrong when $n=2$: the size of $K^*/(K^*)^2$ is at least $4$ (and is exactly $4$ when the residue field characteristic is $2$) while $U_2$ has size $2$. The group $K^*$ is infinite, so you can't swap subgroups and quotient groups.

Comment: Hilbert's thm. 90 says that $H^1(\operatorname{Gal}(K/\mathbb Q_p), K^{\times})$ vanishes if $K$ is Galois over $\mathbb Q_p$ and we equip $K^{\times}$ with the natural Galois action.  If we take a cyclic group $G$ with trivial action on $K$, then $H^1(G,K^{\times}) = \operatorname{Hom}(G,K^{\times})$, which need not be trivial.